# How can I make a "tiny release" upgrade with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, version, upgrade, updates

I'm using jQuery 1.10.0, and it turns out it has a pretty serious bug, which was fixed in jQuery 1.10.1.

On jQuery's [download page](https://jquery.com/download/), it only has jQuery 1.11.3. I don't want to change to a different minor release though, because I'm paranoid that could mess up some of the jQuery in my app.

How can I upgrade my jQuery version to 1.10.1?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), these usually host multiple versions of jQuery. For instance, [Google's CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery) hosts the following versions:

> 2.1.4, 2.1.3, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.3, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 1.11.3, 1.11.2, 1.11.1, 1.11.0, 1.10.2, 1.10.1, 1.10.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.0, 1.8.3, 1.8.2, 1.8.1, 1.8.0, 1.7.2, 1.7.1, 1.7.0, 1.6.4, 1.6.3, 1.6.2, 1.6.1, 1.6.0, 1.5.2, 1.5.1, 1.5.0, 1.4.4, 1.4.3, 1.4.2, 1.4.1, 1.4.0, 1.3.2, 1.3.1, 1.3.0, 1.2.6, 1.2.3

Hence, you can use:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to include the version of jQuery you're looking for

Comment: Wait, that's all I have to do? Wouldn't I have to download something?

Comment: Basically, the CDN hosts the jQuery version for you, so you don't need to download anything. If you do want to use a locally hosted version, you can always [download it](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js) and reference it locally.

Comment: Should I delete the jQuery 1.10.0 files I have downloaded?

Comment: Yes, if you're not using them. Not that they'll interfere but it's just neater.